# Replace string in string list with string list

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace from a list of strings, a found string with multiple strings.
This is what I have so far:

```
private List<string> AddBinList( int CSNum,  List<string> dataLogLines)
    {
        foreach (var line in dataLogLines)
        {
            try
            {
                if (line.Contains("&ALLPASSBINNUMBER&") && line.Contains("&ALLPASSBINNAME&"))
                {
                    List<string> newLines = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var passBin in site[CSNum].Tokens.PassBins)
                    {
                        string outputLine = line.Replace("&ALLPASSBINNUMBER&", passBin.Value.ToString());
                        outputLine = line.Replace("&ALLPASSBINNAME&", passBin.Key);
                        newLines.Add(outputLine);
                    }

                    dataLogLines = dataLogLines.Select(x => x.Replace(line, newLines)).ToList();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return dataLogLines;
    }
```

---

**EDITIORS NOTE:** The problem the OP is having is

```
dataLogLines = dataLogLines.Select(x => x.Replace(line, newLines)).ToList();
```

is giving a compiler error.

Comment: What problem are you having? Also why are you catching all exceptions, it is likely hiding whatever is causing the program to not work.

Comment: the catch is for handling keys not present in dictionary. The replace is what doesn't work. I want to be able to replace from a list of strings, one string with a new list of multiple strings

Comment: `I want to be able to replace from a list of strings, one string with a new list of multiple strings`???? How about posting a sample input, expected output and a brief description?

Comment: This line looks like its going to be a problem, since you are modifying the `dataLogLines` variable while iterating over it. --> `dataLogLines = dataLogLines.Select(x => x.Replace(line, newLines)).ToList();`

Comment: Sample input would be a string list like: {"item1","item2"}. Now I want to replace "item2" with new string list, i.e. {"item3","item4"} so my final list looks like {"item1","item3","item4"}

Comment: @Mercurybullet No that won't be a problem because it does not modify the original list, it returns a new `IEnumberable<string>` and the variable is captured on the fist loop, but you made me figure out what his real problem is... tondre3na, Are you getting a compiler error on `x.Replace(line, newLines)` and that is what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes. Because its expecting a string not a string list.

Comment: When you come here to ask about a error you are getting, please actually tell us that you are getting a error. That is the difference between saying "my car is acting weird" and saying "my breaks do not work when I press on the break petal".

Comment: Ok thanks will do next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sample input would be a string list like: {"item1","item2"}. Now I want to replace "item2" with new string list, i.e. {"item3","item4"} so my final list looks like {"item1","item3","item4"

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2" };
list1 = list1.SelectMany(x => x == "item2" ? new[] { "item3", "item4" } 
                                            : new[] { x })
             .ToList();
```